# How to use Laravel URL::to in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to access this laravel URL inside Javascript:

```
var id = 2;
var href = '{{ URL::to('/bus/'+ id +'') }}';
```

I tried to escape the single quote and `\` before it, like this:

```
var id = 2;
var href = '{{ URL::to(\'/bus/'+ id +'') }}';
```

It's giving me this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''/bus/'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the mis-matched quotes, `id` is a client-side JS variable which is not available in your Laravel logic which runs on the server. To fix this get the URL to `/bus` on the server, then append the `id` to it on the client. Something like this:

```
var id = 2;
var href = '{{ URL::to('/bus/') }}' + id;
```

Note that you may need to append a `/` between the Laravel output and the `id` value, it just depends on how the routes are generated.

Comment: when i hit hhref it showing `http://localhost/BSProject/public/bus3` instead of `http://localhost/BSProject/public/bus/3`

Comment: In that case, as I mentioned, you need to include a `/` between the values: `var href = '{{ URL::to('/bus') }}/' + id;`